# Using RK4 to solve integrals

Tags: python, runge-kutta

The question asks us to solve this integral in python using an Rk4 method `∫sinh()(−5)` from `0` to `5`. Whats the best way to do this, how would you change this to an ODE?

```py
def RK4(f, dx, x0, y0, imax):
    output = np.empty((imax, 3))
    i = 0
    xi = x0
    yi = y0
    while(i < imax):
        k1 = dx*f(xi,yi)
        k2 = dx*f(xi + 0.5*dx, yi + 0.5*k1)
        k3 = dx*f(xi + 0.5*dx, yi + 0.5*k2)
        k4 = dx*f(xi + dx, yi + k3)

        yi = yi + 1/6*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)
        xi += dx
        output[i, 0] = xi
        output[i, 1] = yi[0]
        output[i, 2] = yi[1]
        i += 1
    return output

RK4(0,0,5,100,10)
```

I get a error that for k1 ("int object is not callable")?? how can I fix this or maybe the issue is somewhere else in my code. Thanks for any help. Also the question explicitly asks us to solve the integral using both Simpsons rule and RK4 methods

Comment: Using RK4 here is the same as using the Simpson quadrature rule. Kutta explicitly constructed RK4 as an extension of the Simpson rule to ODE integration.

Comment: in your code, `f = 0`, You can't call it as a function `f(...)`. If you are stuck, just learn from online example such as https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Runge-Kutta_method#Python

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an integer `0` in place of the function. Then in the `k1` line you try to use that integer as function, which gives the reported error, as there is no sensible interpretation of `0(0,5)`. You could use

```
RK4(lambda x,y:0,0,5,100,10)
```

However, with a step size of zero no integration will occur.